# How to get a QFrame position in absolute coordinates in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a custom date edit widget with calendar popup in PyQt5. The calendar is a frameless QDialog, the position of which I have to set using the coordinates of the date edit. Date edit field is placed in QFrame.

The problem is that when I try to get the position of the bottom left corner of the QFrame, I get a QPoint in local coordinates. Using mapToGlobal method gives the same result.

```
print(self.dateEditFrame.geometry().bottomLeft())
print(self.dateEditFrame.mapToGlobal(self.dateEditFrame.geometry().bottomLeft()))

# Output:
# PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, 29)
# PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, 29)
```

When I try to get the absolute position of the QFrame, I get the local coordinates too.

```
print(self.dateEditFrame.pos())

# Output:
# PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()
```

How can I get the position of QFrame in absolute coordinates on the screen?

**UPD**
Here, for example, is some code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(600, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 0, 4, 1)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        print(self.frame.mapToGlobal(self.frame.pos()))
        print(self.frame.mapToGlobal(self.frame.geometry().bottomLeft()))

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the output:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, 29)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  If used correctly I think `mapToGlobal` should give you what you want.

Comment: @G.M. Ok, I added some code

Comment: In the code shown you try to map the widget's geometry *before* it's been shown.  I'm pretty sure that won't work.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me!

Comment: @MarkPetrov please consider that you should also not try to edit pyuic generated files, read how to properly use them in [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: The position is calculated when the widgets are being layouted. And they get layouted just before they get displayed. So you need to let them display first and only then you can query their position. Of course you can do some clever hacks to force layouting immediately but I would advice not to use any hacks if they can be avoided.

Comment: @musicamante thanks, I know that. I made this code just for an example.

Comment: @V.K. ok, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it is going to work, but try using qss to give the position absolute to the frame like this

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.setGeometry(50,50,700, 600)
   
          self.frame = QFrame(self)
          self.frame.setGeometry(50,50, 200, 200)
          self.frame.setStyleSheet("""
          QFrame{
            position: absolute;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 5px;
          }
          """)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = Window()
   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).